# adding a formatted date to VBA excel formula "(Format(Now, "YYYYMMDHH:MM:SS"))"

Tags: excel, vba

To simplify, I have a formula in excel that works, test formula, e.g. `=A1&NOW()`which gives the the following result `IT43775.5901537037`.

I would like to get `IT2019082112:30:01`, therefore i tried the formula below using VBA, as I need this to be in VBA, but but unsuccessfully.

```
HSBC.Sheets(1).Range("AJ1").Formula = "=A1" & (Format(Now, "YYYYMMDHH:MM:SS"))
```

Comment: If you want the formula to update, use: `=A1&TEXT(NOW(), "YYYYMMDHH:MM:SS")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the datetime to be hard-coded:

```
HSBC.Sheets(1).Range("AJ1").Formula = "=A1&""" & (Format(Now, "YYYYMMDHH:MM:SS")) & """"
```

If you want the formula to update, just use `TEXT` to format `NOW`, as pointed out in a comment.